# Logical OR Missing from Prisma with MongoDB

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I was trying yo use MongoDB as database with Prisma, but after few queries, I noticed that Logical OR and NOT are missing.

When I switch the DB to Postgres, everything is at place ( AND, OR, NOT are there).

Am I missing something?

Prisma version is 1.34.0

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Prisma.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3897

> No, these were disabled in the Mongo connector in order to enable filters on relations. We might bring them back in the future, but for now we valued a quicker implementation of relational filters higher than OR, NOT.